# Revoke ex-clolaborator's access to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, security

I have an ubuntu server with django website named `hello` running on it. 
This is how I created user access here:

```
mkdir /hosting/hello
groupadd --system hosting
useradd --system --gid hosting --shell /bin/bash --home-dir /hosting/hello hello
passwd hello
chown -R hello /hosting/hello
chmod -R u+w /hosting/hello
* all project is stored under /hosting/hello directory
```

There are `django` instance and `postgresql` database running on this server.

So, `hello` is a normal non-administrator user, without any extra permissions (I hope it's configured correctly... isn't it?)

Nobody except me knows root password. Several developers are working on this project and they all know password for user `hello`.
Now one developer (let's call him `Bob`) quit his job. I need to make sure that he couldn't access this server (paranoid mode on). So I did this steps  now:

- changed password for user `hello`
- changed password for postgresql database
- removed Bob's ssh public key from server

Is it enough to be sure that Bob can't access server now? I don't want to reinstall everything, but I worry if Bob could leave some backdoors before quitting. There was no reasons for him to do it, but my paranoid mode is still on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a user that did not perform any malicious steps before leaving I think your approach is correct.

However if you are concerned about possible backdoors, I would recommend:

- If you don’t need internet browsing in the server, cut it out on the firewall. If you do, try to be selective on ports and destinations that the server is allowed to.
- monitor the network connections using `netstat` usually different switches give you different pieces of information, use `-p` to see the process id, `-ant` to see all the tcp connections.
- If you found a process generating weird connections, you can follow the files that it uses with `lsof`
- Check on the crontab to see if any scheduled tasks are opening connections. Read `/etc/crontab` and check `crontab -e` from the user he had access, and root.

This should be the way to catch really simple backdoors, however, if you are talking about rootkits, it will be most likely impossible to tell... if you really suspect that the guy did something, I would wipe the server and move the Django instance to a new installation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! So, even if user had no root access, he still could leave some backdoors in users home directory?

Comment: Yes of course, it will probably be much easier to spot, but it is possible indeed